# Where should I store the SQLite DB for my iPhone app?

Tags: ios, iphone, database, sqlite

I have several iOS apps on the market and in all of them I have a small SQLite database file connected to the app to provide the user with my data. Once installed the user customizes this DB by changing certain options.

Until now, all of these apps store the DB in `NSDocumentsDirectory`. After submitting my last update, it was rejected for storing data in the wrong location. For the apps rejected I changed the storage location to `NSCachesDirectory`. I am now afraid that the cache will get cleared and erase the users customizations. The app would still function, the DB would get recreated, but all changed tables would be reset, thereby upsetting users.

Where should this type of database file be stored? Was I right to put it in the Docs dir? According to Apple, the Docs dir is for "Critical Data" which is either user generated data or data needed for proper operation of the app. I feel that it falls under that category, persisting my users settings is proper operation, but who wants to await an appeal?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Apple's file system programming guide for iOS describes the `(application_home)/Library` path as a place to "create custom subdirectories for files you want backed up but not exposed to the user". The `(application_home)/Documents` path is described as "the contents of this directory can be made available to the user through file sharing."

Your databases don't sound like documents, they sound like private caches that users shouldn't know about. I recommend you create a directory such as `(application_home)/Library/Database` and save files there. The cache path you mention doesn't sound like the best option to me.

You should really review the entire [file system programming guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW2) before submitting another app.

Answer (score 2):

6 year update:

Storing the data in the `NSCachesDirectory` caused a bug, as expected, that the users customized data would erase whenever the device felt like it. After many many attempts at arguing the point with Apple app review, I was able to finally post an update where the data is now stored in a custom directory in the `NSDocumentsDirectory` (as it should be) which solved all of the aforementioned issues.

Answer (score 0):

If your database indeed contains user-generated content, then the Documents directory is its proper location.

However, you mention that you are persisting "your users settings"... If the data you are persisting are more akin to settings or preferences, then they should reside in the Defaults subsystem. See the documentation for [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I did use the wrong phrasing with 'persisting'.. I meant to keep the users changes to the database, The above answer suggests the Library set of directories may be the correct spot. In looking into this I found that a more appropriate location may be the Library/Application Support directory. I will be attempting to run some test trials on my data stored there..