# Where to store .sqlite database on iOS

Tags: iphone, core-data

In my app I retrieve, parse and save XML data to a sqlite database via CoreData. This data is essential to the operation of the app and needed for offline use. My minimum target is iOS 4.3

This is not user generated so i cannot store it in **/Library/Documents**

- iOS 5.0 does not support the extended attribute to mark files as "do not backup" therefore, anything outside of **/tmp** & **/Library/Caches** is backed up.

Source : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html

Because of this, I have no other choice but to store my data in the /Library/Caches folder. iOS may purge this directory at any time.

**Does this mean that anytime my app downloads new data ( via xml ) and saves it using ...**
`[managedObjectContext save:&error]`
...  **I will first have to check to see if MyData.sqlite still exists?**

If it doesn't then I will need to "restore" the CoreData stack then alert any other object that may need to get a new pointer to, or modify it's managedObjectContext's persistentStoreCoordinator.

This solution does not seem right, but based on iOS 5.0 not supporting "do not backup", Apple's Data storage guidelines, and the way purging of the /Libraray/Caches directory works, I don't know how there is any other alternative.

Comment: Why you don't want backups of your database? If it's critical to work and you don't want to recreate it when it's purged from tmp or cache, so you want also backups. Am i right? See also other similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433802/when-does-ipad-clear-library-caches. For iOS 5 you can mark folder to not to be backuped (it will save space on iCloud backups).

Comment: Apple is very picky about this. *ahem*, from a rejection:

The iOS Data Storage Guidelines indicate that only content that the user creates using your app, e.g., documents, new files, edits, etc., may be stored in the /Documents directory - and backed up by iCloud.

Comment: As dpjanes said, my question is a result of an app store rejection.  Thom_ek, thank you for that link, any bit of info helps at this point

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where should I store the SQLite DB for my iPhone app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346760/where-should-i-store-the-sqlite-db-for-my-iphone-app)

Answer (score 7):

Nick Lockwood's wonderful StandardPaths library [has an opinion](https://github.com/nicklockwood/StandardPaths/blob/b55e79a5cba25a47b55454575ce90f90f39972d7/StandardPaths/StandardPaths.m#L147-L178); this library stores application-private, not-to-be-pruned, not-to-be-backed-up, persistent-across-app-updates data in `Library/Application Support/Offline Data` by convention.

You are correct though that, for iOS 5.0 and older, any attempt to prevent a file from being backed up will be ineffective.

On iOS 5.0.1 backup-prevention is implemented as follows ([source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html)):

```
const char *filePath = [[fileURL path] fileSystemRepresentation];
const char *attrName = "com.apple.MobileBackup";
u_int8_t attrValue = 1;
setxattr(filePath, attrName, &attrValue, sizeof(attrValue), 0, 0);
```

On iOS 5.1 and above backup-prevention is implemented as follows ([source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html)):

```
[fileURL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]
                   forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey
                    error: &error];
```

Answer (score -1):

DBDATABASE.H

```
  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
   #import <sqlite3.h>
   #import "DetailtableviewViewController.h"
   @interface DBDatabase : NSObject
    {
    NSString *databasePath;
     }
  +(DBDatabase*)getSharedInstance;
   - (BOOL)createDB;
   - (BOOL) saveData:(NSString*)name email:(NSString *)email  
    password:(NSString *)password confirmpassword:
    (NSString*)confirmpassword           
    age:(NSString*)age department:(NSString*)department;


    - (NSArray*) findingEmailid:(NSString*)Emailid password:
    (NSString*)password;
    - (NSArray*)studentdetailbyTableview:(NSString*)email;

    @end
```

DBDATABASE.M

```
   #import "DBDatabase.h"
   static DBDatabase *sharedInstance = nil;
  static sqlite3 *database = nil;
  static sqlite3_stmt *statement = nil;


@implementation DBDatabase
+(DBDatabase*)getSharedInstance{
if (!sharedInstance) {
    sharedInstance = [[super allocWithZone:NULL]init];
    [sharedInstance createDB];
}
return sharedInstance;
 }

 -(BOOL)createDB{
 NSString *docsDir;
NSArray *dirPaths;
// Get the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = dirPaths[0];
// Build the path to the database file
databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[docsDir
 stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"sasi.db"]];    
NSLog(@"CREATED DB PATH :%@", databasePath);

BOOL isSuccess = YES;
NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: databasePath ] == NO)
{
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        char *errMsg;
     const char *sql_stmt ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERDETAILS 
       (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, EMAIL TEXT, 
      PASSWORD TEXT, CONFIRMPASSWORD TEXT, AGE TEXT, DEPARTMENT 
      TEXT)"; 

        if (sqlite3_exec(database, sql_stmt, NULL, NULL, &errMsg)
            != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            isSuccess = NO;
            NSLog(@"Failed to create table");
        }
        sqlite3_close(database);
        return  isSuccess;
    }
    else {
        isSuccess = NO;
        NSLog(@"Failed to open/create database");
    }
    }
return isSuccess;
 }

 -(BOOL) saveData:(NSString*)name email:(NSString *)email password:
 (NSString *)password confirmpassword:(NSString *)confirmpassword 
  age:(NSString*)age department:(NSString*)department;
  {
const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
     NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                           @"INSERT INTO USERDETAILS (name, email,  
  password,confirmpassword,age,department) VALUES (\"%@\", \"%@\", 
   \"%@\",\"%@\", \"%@\", 
 \"%@\")",name,email,password,confirmpassword,age,department ];  

    const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, NULL);
    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else {
        return NO;
    }
    //sqlite3_reset(statement);
     }
return NO;
 }
  -(NSArray*) findingEmailid:(NSString*)Emailid password:    
  (NSString*)password;

 {
const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *selectSql = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                           @"SELECT *from USERDETAILS Where email 
  =\"%@\" and password =\"%@\"",Emailid,password];
    NSLog(@"------>%@",Emailid);

    const char *compare_stmt = [selectSql UTF8String];
    NSMutableArray *resultarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, compare_stmt,-1, &statement, 
   NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            NSString *userName =[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:
   (const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
            [resultarray addObject:userName];
            NSString *password =[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:
   (const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
            [resultarray addObject:password];
            return resultarray;
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"not found");
            return nil;
        }

    }

  }
return nil;
 }
  -(NSArray*)studentdetailbyTableview:(NSString*)email;

 {
const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *selectSql = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                           @"SELECT name,age,department FROM 
  USERDETAILS Where email =\"%@\"",email];
    NSLog(@"------->%@",email);
    const char *insert_stmt = [selectSql UTF8String];
    NSMutableArray *resultarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insert_stmt,-1, &statement, 
  NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
        {
            NSString *userName =[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:
   (const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
            [resultarray addObject:userName];
            NSString *age =[[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const 
    char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
            [resultarray addObject:age];
            NSString *department =[[NSStrin alloc]initWithUTF8String: 
      (const char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];   
            [resultarray addObject:department];

            return resultarray;


        }
        {
            NSLog(@"not found");
            return nil;
        }

    }

}
return nil;
  }

@end
```

REGISTER VI.H

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DBDatabase.h"


@interface RegisterViewController :UIViewController  
   <UITextFieldDelegate,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource>

 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *usernameText1;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *emailidText2;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *passwordText3;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *confirmpwdText4;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *dobText5;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *depatmentText6;
@property (strong,nonatomic)NSArray *depmentArray;
- (IBAction)registerButton:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *departmentPicker;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *registerBttn;
```

@end

REGISTER VIEW.M

```
 #import "RegisterViewController.h"
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import <sqlite3.h>
 #import "DetailtableviewViewController.h"

  @interface RegisterViewController ()
    @end




  @implementation RegisterViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

self.title = @"NEW USER";
_departmentPicker.hidden=YES;
_depmentArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Computer 
Science",@"Civil",@"Mechanical",@"Electonic",nil];   
_registerBttn.enabled =NO;
}
//- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField  
 shouldChangeCharactersInRange:   
(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
 //{
 //    NSInteger maxlength = 25;
 //    {
 //        if(textField == _usernameText1)
   //        {
 //            maxlength =15;
 //        }       
  //        else if(textField ==_dobText5)
  //        {
   //            maxlength =2;
  //        }
 //        
 //        NSUInteger length =[textField.text length]+[string length] 
     - range.length;
  //        return !(length >maxlength);
  //        
   //    }
  //}
 -(BOOL) NSStringIsValidEmail:(NSString *)checkString
 {

  }
  #pragma mark textfield delegate

  - (BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
 }
 -(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField 
  shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:
  (NSString *)string {
 if ((_usernameText1.text.length >0) && (_emailidText2.text.length 
 >0) && (_passwordText3.text.length >0) &&     
 (_confirmpwdText4.text.length >0) && (_dobText5.text.length >0))
//&& (textField == _depatmentText6)
{
    _registerBttn.enabled =YES;
}
else{
    _registerBttn.enabled =NO;
}
return YES;
 }

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
if( (_usernameText1.text.length >0) && (_emailidText2.text.length >0) 
&& (_passwordText3.text.length >0) && (_confirmpwdText4.text.length 
>0) && (_dobText5.text.length >0)  
&& (textField == _depatmentText6)) {

   // _registerBttn.enabled=YES;
    _departmentPicker.hidden=NO;
}
else
{
    //_registerBttn.enabled=NO;
    _departmentPicker.hidden=YES;
  }
  }

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }



 #pragma mark-UIPickerView Datasource

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)   
  pickerView
  {
 return 1;
 }
 - (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView 
 numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component   
 {
 return _depmentArray.count;
 }
 - (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:   
 (NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
 {
return [_depmentArray objectAtIndex:row];
}

 - (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:
 (NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
 {
 if (self.departmentPicker)
 {
    [_depatmentText6 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",    
    [_depmentArray objectAtIndex:row]]];
    _departmentPicker.hidden=YES;
 }
 }


 - (IBAction)registerButton:(id)sender {

BOOL success = NO;
if ([_usernameText1.text isEqualToString:@""]) {

    UIAlertController *alert =[[UIAlertController alloc]init];
    alert =[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"WARNING      ALERT" message:@"Enter your name" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction * ok =[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
        [self.usernameText1 becomeFirstResponder];
    }];

    [alert addAction:ok];
    [_usernameText1 becomeFirstResponder];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
  }

   else if([_emailidText2.text isEqualToString:@""]) {

    UIAlertController *alert =[[UIAlertController alloc]init];
    alert =[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"WARNING ALERT" message:@"Enter  your email" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction * ok =[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                         {
                             [self.emailidText2 becomeFirstResponder];

                         }];
    [_emailidText2 becomeFirstResponder];
    [alert addAction:ok];

    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}

else if(![self NSStringIsValidEmail:self.emailidText2.text ]) {

    UIAlertController *alert =[[UIAlertController alloc]init];
    alert =[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"WARNING ALERT" message:@"Enter your valid emailid" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction * ok =[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
        [self.emailidText2 becomeFirstResponder];
    }];

    [alert addAction:ok];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}

else if ([_passwordText3.text isEqualToString:@""]) {

    UIAlertController *alert =[[UIAlertController alloc]init];
    alert =[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"WARNING ALERT" message:@"Enter your password" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction * ok =[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
        [self.passwordText3 becomeFirstResponder];
    }];

    [alert addAction:ok];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}

else if (_passwordText3.text.length<6) {

    UIAlertController *alert =[[UIAlertController alloc]init];
    alert =[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"WARNING ALERT" message:@"Enter the password greater then six characters" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction * ok =[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
        [self.passwordText3 becomeFirstResponder];
    }];

    [alert addAction:ok];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}

else if([_confirmpwdText4.text isEqualToString:@""]) {

    UIAlertController *alert =[[UIAlertController alloc]init];
    alert =[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"WARNING ALERT" message:@"Enter the confirm password" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction * ok =[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
        [self.confirmpwdText4 becomeFirstResponder];
    }];
    [alert addAction:ok];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

}
else if (_confirmpwdText4.text.length<6) {

    UIAlertController *alert =[[UIAlertController alloc]init];
    alert =[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"WARNING ALERT" message:@"Enter the confirmpassword greater then sixcharacters" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction * ok =[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
        [self.confirmpwdText4 becomeFirstResponder];
    }];

    [alert addAction:ok];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}

else if ([_dobText5.text isEqualToString:@""]) {

    UIAlertController *alert =[[UIAlertController alloc]init];
    alert =[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"WARNING ALERT" message:@"Enter your age" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction * ok =[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
        [self.dobText5 becomeFirstResponder];
    }];

    [alert addAction:ok];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
else if ([_depatmentText6.text isEqualToString:@""]) {

    UIAlertController *alert =[[UIAlertController alloc]init];
    alert =[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"WARNING ALERT" message:@"Enter your department" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction * ok =[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
        [self.depatmentText6 becomeFirstResponder];
    }];

    [alert addAction:ok];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}

else if (![_passwordText3.text isEqualToString:_confirmpwdText4.text]) {

    {
        UIAlertController *alert =[[UIAlertController alloc]init];
        alert =[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"WARNING ALERT" message:@"Enter your password" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        UIAlertAction * ok =[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
            [self.confirmpwdText4 becomeFirstResponder];
        }];

        [alert addAction:ok];
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}

else {
    success = [[DBDatabase getSharedInstance]saveData:_usernameText1.text email:_emailidText2.text password: _passwordText3.text confirmpassword:_confirmpwdText4.text age:_dobText5.text department:_depatmentText6.text];

_departmentPicker.hidden=YES;

    UIAlertController *alert =[[UIAlertController alloc]init];
    alert =[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"SUCCESS ALERT" message:@"New User Registered succesfully" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction
                                   actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", @"Cancel action")
                                   style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                                   {
                                       NSLog(@"Cancel action");
                                   }];

    UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction
                               actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK action")
                               style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                               handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                               {
                                   NSLog(@"OK action");
                                   [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                                   _usernameText1.text=@"";_emailidText2.text=@"";_passwordText3.text=@"";_confirmpwdText4.text=@"";_dobText5.text=@"";_depatmentText6.text=@"";
                                   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"New User" sender:self];
                               }];

    [alert addAction:cancelAction];
    [alert addAction:okAction];


    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}

if (success == NO) {

    {
        UIAlertController *alert =[[UIAlertController alloc]init];
        alert =[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"WARNING ALERT" message:@"NIL" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        UIAlertAction * ok =[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
        [alert addAction:ok];
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES

  completion:nil];
    }
   }
   }
  @end
```

VIEW CONTR.H(LOGIN)

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
 #import <sqlite3.h>
 #import "DBDatabase.h"


 @interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>

 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *emailidText;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *passwordText;
    - (IBAction)newregisterButton2:(id)sender;
  - (IBAction)loginButton1:(id)sender;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *logBttn;


@end
```

VIEW CONTROLL.M

```
 #import "ViewController.h"
 #import "DBDatabase.h"
 @interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
self.title=@"LOGIN FORM";
self.logBttn.enabled =NO;

 }
 -(BOOL) NSStringIsValidEmail:(NSString *)checkString
 {
 }

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
if((_emailidText.text.length > 0) && (_passwordText.text.length <10))
{
      _logBttn.enabled =YES;
}
else {
      _logBttn.enabled = NO;

      }
    }
 #pragma mark-UITextFieldDelegate
-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

[textField resignFirstResponder];
return YES;
  }
 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }

- (IBAction)newregisterButton2:(id)sender
 {
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"add" sender:self];
}

 - (IBAction)loginButton1:(id)sender {

 NSArray *data =[[DBDatabase    
 getSharedInstance]findingEmailid:_emailidText.text 
 password:_passwordText.text];
if( [_emailidText.text isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[data objectAtIndex:1]]] ||
    [_passwordText.text isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[data objectAtIndex:2]]]) {

  UIAlertController *alert =[[UIAlertController alloc]init];
   alert =[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"SUCCESS ALERT" message:@"New User Login success" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

   UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction
                            actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", @"OK action")
                            style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                             handler:^(UIAlertAction *action)
                             {
                                  NSLog(@"OK action");
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Detail" sender:self];
                                   _emailidText.text=@"";
                                 _passwordText.text=@"";
                              }];


    [alert addAction:okAction];

   [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
    [self.activityView startAnimating];
   //        [self.activityView stopAnimating];
}

else if(self.emailidText == nil || [self.emailidText.text isEqualToString:@""]) {

    UIAlertController *alert =[[UIAlertController alloc]init];
    alert =[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"WARNING ALERT" message:@"Enter your emailid" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction * ok =[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle
                         :@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                             [self.emailidText becomeFirstResponder];
                         }];
    [alert addAction:ok];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}

else if(![self NSStringIsValidEmail:_emailidText.text ]) {

    UIAlertController *alert =[[UIAlertController alloc]init];
    alert =[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"WARNING ALERT" message:@"Enter your valid emailid" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction * ok =[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle
                         :@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                             [self.emailidText becomeFirstResponder];
                         }];

    [alert addAction:ok];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}

else if(self.passwordText == nil || [self.passwordText.text isEqualToString:@""]) {

    UIAlertController *alert =[[UIAlertController alloc]init];
    alert =[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"WARNING ALERT" message:@"Enter you password" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction * ok =[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle
                         :@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                             [self.passwordText becomeFirstResponder];
                         }];

    [alert addAction:ok];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}

else if(![_passwordText.text isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[data objectAtIndex:2]]]) {

    UIAlertController *alert =[[UIAlertController alloc]init];
    alert =[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"WARNING ALERT" message:@"Enter correct password" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction * ok =[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle
                         :@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {
                             [self.passwordText becomeFirstResponder];
                         }];
    [alert addAction:ok];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}

else {

    UIAlertController *alert =[[UIAlertController alloc]init];
    alert =[UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"WARNING ALERT" message:@"Email is not register" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    UIAlertAction * ok =[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Not Register" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action){
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"add" sender:self];
        _emailidText.text=@"";
        _passwordText.text=@"";
    }];

    [alert addAction:ok];
    _emailidText.text=@"";
    _passwordText.text=@"";
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
 }

 #pragma mark - Navigation

 // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a  
  - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender: 
 (id)sender {

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Detail"]) {
    DetailtableviewViewController *obj = 
 segue.destinationViewController;
    obj.mailid = _emailidText.text;
}
// Get the new view controller using [segue     
 destinationViewController].
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}

@end
```

DETAIL TABLE VIEW.H

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DBDatabase.h"

 @interface DetailtableviewViewController :      
 UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *detailView;
    @property (strong,nonatomic)NSString *mailid;

@end
```

DETAIL.M

```
#import "DetailtableviewViewController.h"
 #import "DetailTableViewCell.h"

 @interface DetailtableviewViewController ()

 @end

 @implementation DetailtableviewViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.mailid];

 }

 - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

 }

  #pragma mark-UITableView datasourse

 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

return 1;
  }

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return 1;
 }

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *cellid = @"cell";
DetailTableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellid];
NSArray *data=[[DBDatabase 
getSharedInstance]studentdetailbyTableview:[NSString 
stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.title]];

{
    cell.nameText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[data 
 objectAtIndex:0]];
    cell.ageText.text =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[data 
 objectAtIndex:1]];
    cell.departmentText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[data 
 objectAtIndex:2]];
    return cell;
}
 }

 /*
 #pragma mark - Navigation



 @end
```

DETAIL TABLECELL.H

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @interface DetailTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameText;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ageText;
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *departmentText;

 @end
```

DETAIL CELL.M

```
 import "DetailTableViewCell.h"

  @implementation DetailTableViewCell

 - (void)awakeFromNib {
[super awakeFromNib];
// Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
}

 @end
```