# SQLite isolated from other apps

Tags: sqlite

I cannot find an answer after searching on the internet, but if my app creates a database on mobile device named 'myDB' with a table called 'users' what happens if another vendor's app on the user's device creates the exact same name? Are the databases isolated by app?

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about a Android device: yes, other apps can't access your app database. (unless they have root access)

> Android provides full support for SQLite databases. Any databases you create will be accessible by name to any class in the application, but not outside the application.

http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Comment: Thanks for the reply! How about for iOS?

Comment: I never used iOS, but I think there is a way to store the database file in a private directory. (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9346784/2047679)